# How to run only relevant tests on jenkins?

Tags: testing, jenkins

Disclaimer: I'm not at all a skilled Jenkins user.

I was looking for a plugin to allow me to run only tests affected by the latest commits, in maven-built projects, but could find neither a maven plugin smart enough to not run all tests again, nor a jenkins plugin doing this. Is there a way to achieve this?

Say, for example, I have a project consisting of A.java, testA.java, B.java and testB.java. I have jenkins configured to run a build and test for each commit. I have just commited a change to A.java, but not to B.Java, and there's no dependency from testB.java and B.java to A.java. I don't want Jenkins to run testB.java when it checks out fresh sources. If ther3e was a dependency from B.java or testB.java to A.java, I'd like jenkins to figure this out, and run testB.java too.

Background: running all tests in a project is too time consuming. Running only a fixed set of tests leaves bug holes for bugs. Running all tests which might be broken by a change by hand is error prone.

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to do this. You may want to split up your applications into more granular libraries and tell Jenkins to rebuild only on a dependency change. Even if this alleviates your issues, it will not fully achieve exactly what you are looking to do. If running all tests in a single project is too time consuming, it may (and I stress the word "may") mean that the project has too many responsibilities and needs to be refactored.

Comment: It sounds like the real problem you are having is "we have to wait too long for the results of the build if we wait for all of the tests."  The solution for that is [splitting the build into stages](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Splitting+a+big+job+into+smaller+jobs).  I wouldn't recommend only running a certain set of tests.  It assumes that A and B will never have cross dependencies.  It's far too easy for a developer to break that assumption.  In the case they really are totally independent, then there should be independent jobs, not one job.